# Integrate custom content type with drupal commerce custom product, how?

Tags: views, 7, commerce

What should / can I do if I want that:

1. The names of my custom content type in a select box as values of
   that select box in my drupal commerce custom product
2. If any of the value is selected from there then, the fields from the
   selected custom content type should be displayed on the same drupal
   commerce's add new product page?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't understand your requirement..

Comment: @RajeevK I want to populate the values into my list text field with the names of my custom content type

Comment: User hook_form_alter to modify the form, add a select & get all content type from DB, list them in the added selectbox..